# Re-raise error if wrong type

Tags: vbscript

I'm looking for a specific database error when doing a query. If the error is not found then I would like standard error handling to be used.

```
On Error Resume Next

db.execute(strSQL)

If db.Errors.Count > 0 Then
   If InStr(db.Errors(0).Description, "IX_Code") Then
      ...
   Else
      * rethrow here *
   End If
End If
```

Is this possible?

I tried...

```
On Error GoTo 0

Err.Raise 22, "Big Error", "Hello World!"
```

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I added this code, which I found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675540(v=vs.85).aspx)...

```
    For Each errLoop In db.Errors

        strError = "Error #" & errLoop.Number & "<br>" & _
            "   " & errLoop.Description & "<br>" & _
            "   (Source: " & errLoop.Source & ")" & "<br>" & _
            "   (SQL State: " & errLoop.SQLState & ")" & "<br>" & _
            "   (NativeError: " & errLoop.NativeError & ")" & "<br>"

        Response.Clear
        Response.Write("<p>" & strError & "</p>")
        Response.End

    Next
```